# useState set method inside useEffect hook not updating till refreching the page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I am trying to update a **user** when a **token** was changed. I have two hooks which are **useToken** (deals with token when login and logout events ) and **useUser** (update the user after any change in token value). I used them inside a **HeaderHelper** which is a functional component returns a **Header Component** that accept **user, token, setToken and navigate as props.** In the latter, I write a function called **afterLogin** to invoke **setToken** in the aim of updating the **token** field and invoke also a navigate hook to redirect to the appropriate route.

**The problem is after logging in, the user field did not get any value and stay "null", Although the setToken and useEffect were invoked. To get the result that I aim to get I should to refresh the browser and it's obviously not practical.**

> quote **NOTE:** useUser has a token field as a part of its state. and the HeaderHelper has a user and token as a part of its state.

here is the code of useToken Hook:

```
export const useToken = () => {
    const [ token, setToken ] = useState(()=>{
        return sessionStorage.getItem('token');
    });

    function setTokenStorage (newToken) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', newToken);
        setToken(newToken);
    }

    return [token, setTokenStorage ];
}
```

here is the code of useUser Hook:

```
export const useUser = () =>  {
    const [ token ] = useToken();
    
    const getPayloadFromToken = token => {
        console.log(token);
        const encodedPayload = token.split('.')[1];
        console.log(JSON.parse(atob(encodedPayload)), ': encodedPayload');
        return JSON.parse(atob(encodedPayload));
    }

    const [ user, setUser] = useState(()=>{
        // console.log('token from user useState', token , '***');
        if(!token) {
            console.log(token);
            return {};
        };
        // console.log(getPayloadFromToken(token));
        return getPayloadFromToken(token);
    });

    useEffect( ()=>{
        console.log('token from user useEffect', token , '***');
        if(!token) {
            console.log('user will become null');
            setUser({});
        }else{
            console.log(' useEffect ');
            setUser(getPayloadFromToken(token));
        }
    },[token]);

    return  [user];
}
```

Here is the code of HeaderHelper Component:

```
export const HeaderHelper = (props) => {
    const [user]  = useUser();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [token, setToken] = useToken();
    return <Header navigate={ navigate } token={token} setToken={ setToken } user={ user } {...props}/>
}
```

Here is the code of Header Component:

```
class Header extends Component{
    constructor (props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { ... }
    }
    handleLogin(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({successSingIn : false});
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "email" : this.email.value,
                "password" : this.password.value,
                "type" : this.type.value,
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type" : "application/json"},
            credentials: "same-origin"
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.ok){
                return response;
            }else{
                const error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ' : ' + response.statusText);
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }
        }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log('response from backend: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
            if (response.status) {
                this.setState({ failToLogIn : '' });
                this.afterLogin(response.user.token);
            }else{
                this.setState({ failToLogIn : 'something wrong, try again with valid information!' });
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ failToLogIn : 'something wrong' });
            console.log('something wrong with login process\n' , error.message)
        });
    }
}
```

and here is the code of afterLogin function:

```
afterLogin = (userToken) => {
        this.toggleLoginModel();
        console.log('userToken: ', userToken);
        this.props.setToken(userToken);
        this.props.navigate('/dashboard');
        
    }
```

**Summary:** *-This is how I think-*
-1 the guest make a login request.
-2 afterLogin function invoked after a successfully login.
-3 then, setToken invoked, leads to invoke that function inside useEffect. And cause a re-render for HeaderHelper.
-4 finally, setUser will be invoked and cause a re-render for HeaderHelper.
-5 after all of that a token and user should have values, unfortunately that didn't happen.
So how can I solve this issue?

thank you!

Comment: Does the `useToken` hook used in `useUser` hook share any state with the `useToken` hook used in `HeaderHelper`? Where is `afterLogin` called? Can you include all relevant code, like `useToken` and `Header`?

Comment: @drewReese I thought that are two different instances, but in the **useToken** hook I save/delete the token in/from the **sessionStorage**. and **afterLogin** called after a success request to the server using fetch API. I have updated the post with the appropriate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, looks like each `useToken` hook maintains its own state. The `setToken` `Header` is using is from the `useToken` whereas nothing updates the `token` state of the `useToken` hook that `useUsers` is using, so the `useEffect` hook won't retrigger.

What you might try doing is to return the `token` and `setToken` from the `useToken` hook that `useUser` is using so there's only the one instance.

```
export const useUser = () =>  {
  const [token, setToken] = useToken();
    
  const getPayloadFromToken = token => {
    console.log(token);
    const encodedPayload = token.split('.')[1];
    console.log(JSON.parse(atob(encodedPayload)), ': encodedPayload');
    return JSON.parse(atob(encodedPayload));
  }

  const [user, setUser] = useState(() => {
    // console.log('token from user useState', token , '***');
    if (!token) {
      console.log(token);
      return {};
    };
    // console.log(getPayloadFromToken(token));
    return getPayloadFromToken(token);
  });

  useEffect( ()=>{
    console.log('token from user useEffect', token , '***');
    if (!token) {
      console.log('user will become null');
      setUser({});
    } else {
      console.log(' useEffect ');
      setUser(getPayloadFromToken(token));
    }
  }, [token]);

  return [user, token, setToken];
}
```

...

```
export const HeaderHelper = (props) => {
  const [user, token, setToken] = useUser();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <Header
      {...props}
      navigate={navigate}
      token={token}
      setToken={setToken}
      user={user}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. but I still confused, without the solution you provide, the *useEffect* hook retrigger any way, I have tested it with this line `console.log(" useEffect ")` in *useUser* hook. why this happen? other Qst when the **token** is updated in **afterLogin**, a re-render for **HeaderHelper** will invoked, so this line `const [user] = useUser();` will be re-executed, isn't? If yes, the *useUser* hook will use the new token when defining its state. and should return a user object after executing this line `setUser(getPayloadFromToken(token));` to pass it as props. is that correct?

Comment: @2kali Oh, interesting. Perhaps something else triggered a rerender which reruns the hooks and `token` getting redeclared in the body, but the value wasn't updated, i.e. the reference changed so the `useEffect` callback was called, but the value is the same. Yes, `const [user, ....] = useUser()` will run again when `HeaderHelper` rerenders. If the token updates and triggers the `useEffect` and should call `setUser` and update the `userState`. Is it all working now as you expect?